# How can we paginate when before we reach max extent in flutter ListView?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am currently paginating at max extent.
I have written this code :

```
if (scrollController.position.pixels ==
        scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
      setState(() {
        startIndex += 10;
      });
      context.read<MyBloc>().add(
            GetDataFromMyBloc(startIndex),
          );
    }
```

I have tried this test also :

```
 if (scrollController.position.pixels >
        scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent - 200) {}
```

But it's making scroll very laggy, because API is called multiple times. How can I make it call only one time ?

Answer (score 1):

`==` is not a good practice in this case. try using something like:

```dart
if (scrollController.position.pixels >
        scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent - 200) {}
```

just you should handle in your stateful widget or your bloc not
to fetch data multiple times.

Comment: as I said. you should check if it is the first time you enter in this block. for example you can add a boolean to your stateful widget. with default value of true and when change your if to: `(scrollController.position.pixels >
        scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent - 200 && theBoolean) `

Comment: Yeah you are right, it should work. Let me try

Answer (score 0):

```
_scrollController.addListener(() {
  if (_scrollController.position.isScrollingNotifier.value ||
      _scrollController.position.extentAfter < 500) {
    if (_scrollController.position.atEdge) {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels == 0) {
        // You're at the top.
      } else {
        // you are at the above bottom
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

This may be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

In addition to indicating that you want to load the data when you reach the bottom of the page, it is important to **add a second condition that prevents an unintentional scroll action from calling the `loadData`** *(or any other)* **method more than once**, thus avoiding multiple calls and the data duplication if be a pagination!

Here an code example:

```dart
scrollController.addListener(() {
    if (scrollController.position.pixels > scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent - 200) {
        // you must use any way to verify if the state of page (or method) ISN'T in loading
        if (controller.state != loading) { 
            controller.loadData(controller.page);
        }
    }
});
```

[image: Ignoring the condition]   | [image: With condition != loading]

On left, whithou the condition to verify if isn't loading data, on right, with the *magic* condition... ✨